# Is System.Threading.Tasks available in Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, system, visual-studio-express

Recently i start to learn about parallel programming. In that i like to apply parallel for so i need `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. Now i am using Visual Studio 2010 Express edition. Is this option available in that edition?I tried in this edition but it not come.but i used another option of .netframework like ZIP method in that same edition.

Comment: yes i tried but unable to use that namespace

Answer (score 2):

The namespace was introduced in the .NET 4.0 framework, so unless you target an earlier framework, it will be available.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's avaiable in all versions of Visual Studio 2010, because it it part of the .NET-Framework

Answer (score 1):

you can use system.threading.tasks but with Visual Studio Express there is no support for multi-thread debugging i believe

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is part of the .Net 4 framework.